# C/C++ codehighlighter in visual studio 2005

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2005, visual-c++-2005, codehighlighter

I just starting using VS2005 and I wish to have code highlighting in C/C++. The VS menu Tools->Options->TextEditor->C/C++ is very poor.
I come from PHP and there the IDE's are very friendly when is about highlighting. I didn't expect that Visual Studio to be so poor at this kind of options.

Can you recommend me a free tool/plugin/lib in order to have code highlighting for C/C++?

Comment: Do you mean block highlight or search highlighting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not free, but [Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/) has some really nice highlighting.

Another (suboptimal for you) solution is to switch editors.  Emacs is infinitely configurable.  I believe that [Eclipse CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/) and [NetBeans](http://www.netbeans.org/) have better syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 1):

We also use [Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/) where I work; I would highly recommend it.  Beyond simple highlighting it has refactorization tools, go to definition, auto completion and more.